# Combining Persistents SqlPersistT with Servants Handler

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm trying to define a helper function that will allow me to run queries using a connection pool provided when run in the `Reader` monad. I would like to define a function that will abstract away the `asks` part of fetching the pool, like so:

```
type Config = Config { getPool :: ConnectionPool }

type App = ReaderT Config

runQuery :: MonadBaseControl IO m => SqlPersistT m a -> App m a
runQuery query =
  asks getPool >>= lift . runSqlQuery
```

Though I am having trouble getting this to compile... I could have sworn this code had worked on a previous project, and low and behold it had. When I went to look at the definitions of `Handler` (the `m` I want in `App m`), and `runSqlQuery` they both differ. It seems that `Handler` has an instance for `MonadBaseControl IO m` whereas `runSqlQuery` uses `MonadUnliftIO`, however, looking back to the change prior to when `MonadUnliftIO` was added, `runSqlQuery` used `MonadBaseControl IO m`... which I presume is why my previous code worked in this instance.

So I suppose my question is, how can I change my implementation of `runQuery` to support the fact that `runSqlQuery` is based off of `MonadUnliftIO` now? I had a look through the functions `MonadUnliftIO` provides (namely `unliftIO`) but I have been unable to figure out a way to make the types fit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this may be an intentional design descision of `MonadUnliftIO`, looking at the readme here https://www.stackage.org/package/unliftio under 'Limitations' it states that it does not support "Transformers with multiple exit points (e.g., ExceptT)", and Servant's `Handler` is a wrapper around `ExceptT`. I may just need to find another way of writing this code.

Answer (score -1):

This compiles with `persistent-2.8.2`:

```
runQuery :: MonadUnliftIO m => ReaderT SqlBackend m b -> App m b
runQuery query =
    asks getPool >>= lift . runSqlPool query
```

Comment: Now how would I run that with http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.14.1/docs/Servant-Server-Internal-Handler.html ?